# Cycling in Berlin during winter

Tags: bicycles, berlin, winter

I'm planning a trip to Berlin next winter with a friend. We'll be staying two months and are thinking about using bikes as our main way of getting around the city.
Does it snow way too much for this to be feasible? Is it safe or recommended? Are there any alternatives?
Cheers!

Comment: Depends on what you are used to and what you can handle. Some people cycle all winter in Toronto and Montreal, others stop cycling when the temperature drops below 10C.

Comment: @Willeke I once heard, from a Canadian, no less, that there's no such thing as bad weather, only bad clothes.  For one thing, the -5 to -10 range is better than the -5 to +5 range because it's a lot less wet and messy.

Comment: You do not need to tell me, I cycle to work every working day and our winters are mild, with +5 to -5 as most common temperatures and rain or sleet to be expected all winter.

Comment: There is not usually a lot of constant snow in Berlin. It might snow, but you can't count on it. If you don't mind cold, you're fine. Most hotels in the city still rent their bikes for day-trips, just fewer than in summer. People bike to work. There is certainly a lot less, but that's because commuters usually hurry up, and it's not pleasant to do that if you can't shower at work during winter, plus it's dark during your commute. For a traveler those points don't really matter.  So to sum up, there might be snow or ice, but usually not a lot, if at all. But with weather you never know.